# How to search using appengine search api with multiple search terms?

Tags: java, python, search, google-search

I want to use the search api to query for a set of strings instead of a single long string sentence.

For example : If the user searches for "where is the dog", then I should make a query which will search whether any of these words is present in the search index. i.e., if the document contains the word "where" it should return that result.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer ... I just want to use a OR clause in between all the words.

Example: Search query by user: "where is the dog"

Query that we  need to execute : "where OR is OR the OR dog"

EDITED : 
Note: But OR is expensive operation and might increase your cost you can check it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/best_practices)